# How to properly serialize message protobuf when sending to kafka (Python)?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to send a message to kafka. I create messages imitating protobuf (using the proto-plus library) where there is a message attached to another, serialize it, but in fact something is sent that is not clear instead of a bit sequence:

```
'\n\x0cTest sending\x12I\n/type.googleapis.com/_default_package.WrapperMsg\x12\x16\n\x14Test for wrapper msg'
```

Please, maybe someone used this library, and know what could be wrong? Or maybe you have an example of other libraries that helped solve such a question? Below is an example of how I tried to do this:

```
import proto
from google.protobuf import any_pb2


"""A class is created that simulates the data in the proto file with library proto-plus"""
class MsgEnum(proto.Enum):
    EXAMPLE_ENUM = 0


class WrapperMsg(proto.Message):
    WrapperField = proto.Field(proto.STRING, number=1)


class MsgForSending(proto.Message):
    SendingField = proto.Field(proto.STRING, number=1)
    AnyField = proto.Field(any_pb2.Any, number=2)
    EnumField = proto.Field(MsgEnum, number=3)


"""Created WrapperMsg class object and pack in Any. 
Any is necessary because there may be several variants of wrapper messages here"""

wrapper_msg = WrapperMsg(WrapperField='Test for wrapper msg')

any_msg_convert = any_pb2.Any()
any_msg_convert.Pack(wrapper_msg._pb)

""" Created MsgForSending object with a wrapper_msg inside"""
sending_msg = MsgForSending(SendingField='Test sending',
                            AnyField=any_msg_convert,
                            EnumField=MsgEnum.EXAMPLE_ENUM)

"""serialized it"""
serialize_msg = MsgForSending.serialize(sending_msg)
```

Comment: Why not use schema registry? https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/protobuf_producer.py